# Apache Camel RabbitMQ consumers leaves back extra threads running

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have built an app which starts multiple RabbitMQ consumers. When I start the app in debug mode in eclipse, I can see desired numbers of threads spawned as can be seen in the Debug window:

[image]

The app deals with several RabbitMQ queues plus some seda queues. The app continues executing by processing and moving messages from one queue to another.

There are at least 7 routes starting from RabbitMQ consumer. These routes roughly looks like this:

```
from("rabbitmq://url")
.process(Processor1.class)
.process(Processor2.class)
```

There is one specific start queue. Depending upon messages published, the message flow from different sequence of queues. So I was testing different sequence flows by publishing different messages to the start queue. After testing some flows by publishing different messages to the start queue, I realized that it spawned many new threads. And even after that sequence flow finishes (that is the message leaves final queue and the final processor in the camel route also executes completely), the thread is left back in running state. I found many such threads added up after I tested multiple flows. Five such threads can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Above are just five extra threads, however this count shoots fast enough as I test multiple complex flow. I have came across 44 threads count. So I was wondering what wrong I am doing. Do I have to explicitly stop the route threads in some way? Did I miss/forget some configuration that I must on the camel route? Why is this happening? Is it normal?

**PS:** My machine is excessively slow on RAM, just 4GB. It runs two lightweight db servers, two web apps, eclipse and my main (above) aap. Most of the time, 3.7 GBs are full. Some times it takes time for a breakpoint (inside camel processor) to hit when I publish a message in the queue. Can such machine be the reason
for erratic threads leaving behind? (Though I primarily think its me missing some setting on the routes)

Comment: Did you check if those consumers have finished their work? Maybe they wait on some IO operation like network and/or disk IO? It especially easy in java to have threads waiting on network IO if you do a lot of connections.